# Number of monomorphisms $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

In my abstract algebra class, we have been tasked to find all monomorphisms $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C}$. The book (Stewart's Galois Theory) gives an example for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \to \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, which I mostly understand. There are 3 such monomorphisms because you can essentially permute the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ three ways in $\mathbb{C}$ (a better explanation would be welcome). However, for my problem the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}:\mathbb{Q}$ is 1, so my thoughts are that there is only the identity monomorphism. Is this true? A hint would be wonderful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a ring monomorphism. What can $f(1)$ be? Show that the value of $f(1)$ determines $f(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and hence $f(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: More generally let $k$ be a prime field and $\varphi: k \rightarrow K$ a ring monomorphism. Then $\varphi(k)$ is the prime subfield of $K$

Comment: $f(1)$ has to be 1 right? I see now how $f(1)$ determines $f(n)$.

Comment: @Jeremy: Yup, that's right.

Comment: @Zev great, thank you!

Comment: Why does $f(1)$ determine $f(n)$? I see: $f(n)=f(n-1)f(1)=f(n-2)f(1)=\cdots=f(1)$

Comment: @hhh: What you've written is incorrect. For any ring homomorphism
$$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)\qquad\qquad f(a\cdot b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$$
so for example,
$$f(3)=f(1+1+1)=f(1)+f(1)+f(1)$$